# Do you have this template for writing article?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, theorems

Here I find this is an interesting template. If you have it please kindly help to share it with me. Like the problem box, theorem box, and the first page of the article.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: A starting point could be `tcolorbox` package http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

Answer (score 3):

With `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}%<--- for testing purpose only 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

% Title page layout
\title{My wonderful article}
\date{March 21, 2021}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \begin{titlepage}
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
       sharp corners,enhanced,
       fontupper=\Huge\bfseries,
       halign=center,
       colframe=red,
       colback=white,
       colupper=red,
       shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{0mm}{red}]
    \@title
    \end{tcolorbox}\vspace{2cm}
    \begin{center}
        \Large\@date
    \end{center}\vspace*{\fill}
    \end{titlepage}%
}
\makeatother

% Box layouts
\tcbset{
  mybox/.style={
    enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm, xshift=-5pt},
    colframe=white,
    boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white, drop lifted shadow=gray}
  },
  thtitle/.style={adjusted title={Theorem~\thetcbcounter\ifstrempty{#1}{\ignorespaces}{~#1}}},
  prtitle/.style={adjusted title={Problem~\thetcbcounter\ifstrempty{#1}{\ignorespaces}{~#1}}},
} 

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{theorem}[1][]{%
    mybox,
    colback=pink!30!white,
    colbacktitle=red,
    thtitle={},
    #1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{problem}[1][]{%
    mybox,
    colback=cyan!10!white,
    colbacktitle=cyan,
    prtitle={},
    #1}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% circled page number
\newcommand*\circlenum[1]{\tikz{\node[shape=circle,fill=cyan,inner sep=2.5pt, text=white] {#1};}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\circlenum{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle\doublespacing
\section{First section}
\begin{theorem}
  \blindtext%<--- for testing purpose only
\end{theorem}
\blindtext%<--- for testing purpose only
\begin{problem}
  \blindtext%<--- for testing purpose only
\end{problem}
\blindtext%<--- for testing purpose only
\section{Second section}
\begin{theorem}[thtitle={My theorem}]
  \blindtext%<--- for testing purpose only
\end{theorem}
\blindtext%<--- for testing purpose only
\begin{problem}[prtitle={My problem}]
  \blindtext%<--- for testing purpose only
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]